# HashMap Key/Value reference

Tags: java, hashmap

Is there a way in Java to check if a `HashMap` value belongs to a specific key?

Example :

```
if (Object.getId().equals(pairs.getKey()) && 
    pairs.getValue().BelongsToThisKey(pairs.getKey())==true) {   

   // do whatever...   
}
```

I know it is strange but this is the check I have to perform..

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you mean `if(pairs.get(Key) == Value)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
boolean doesValueBelongToKey(Map map, Object key, Object value) {
    if(map.containsKey(key) && map.get(key).equals(value))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Can be simplified to `return map.containsKey(key) && map.get(key).equals(value);`, of course.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a way in Java to check if HashMap value belongs to a specific key ?

Just get the value for the specific key using `get()`, if it is not null then your map contains it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way in Java to check if HashMap value belongs to a specific
>   key ?

A `HashMap` mapping is `1-1`.  Simply look it up.  If it's not null, then it matches your key.